# spring eureka security Batch update failure with HTTP status code 401

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I study spring cloud eureka , cloud and they works finely . But after adding security in eureka service , it met some errors .

All the code and errors details is in https://github.com/keryhu/eureka-security

The eureka service application.yml

```
security:
  user:
    name: user
    password: password

eureka: 
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
  server:
    wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty: 0
```

And The config-service application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
```

config-service application.yml

```
eureka:
  client:
    registry-fetch-interval-seconds: 5
    serviceUrl:
       defaultZone: http://user:password@${domain.name:localhost}:8761/eureka/

spring:  
  cloud:
     config:
       server:
         git:
           uri: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo
           basedir: target/config
```

> There is errors exported after starting the config-service:

```
2016-04-10 11:22:39.402 ERROR 80526 --- [get_localhost-3] c.n.e.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor   : Batch update failure with HTTP status code 401; discarding 1 replication tasks
2016-04-10 11:22:39.402  WARN 80526 --- [get_localhost-3] c.n.eureka.util.batcher.TaskExecutors    : Discarding 1 tasks of TaskBatchingWorker-target_localhost-3 due to permanent error
2016-04-10 11:23:09.411 ERROR 80526 --- [get_localhost-3] c.n.e.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor   : Batch update failure with HTTP status code 401; discarding 1 replication tasks
2016-04-10 11:23:09.412  WARN 80526 --- [get_localhost-3] c.n.eureka.util.batcher.TaskExecutors    : Discarding 1 tasks of TaskBatchingWorker-target_localhost-3 due to permanent error
2016-04-10 11:23:39.429 ERROR 80526 --- [get_localhost-3] c.n.e.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor   : Batch update failure with HTTP status code 401; discarding 1 replication tasks
2016-04-10 11:23:39.430  WARN 80526 --- [get_localhost-3] c.n.eureka.util.batcher.TaskExecutors    : Discarding 1 tasks of TaskBatchingWorker-target_localhost-3 due to permanent error
```

Comment: Can you try with Brixton.RC2?

Comment: @spencergibb I  use Brixton.RC1

Comment: Yes, try with RC2 please, if there is still a problem, we can look at it.

Comment: @spencergibb , i have update to RC2, but eureka still has `Batch update failure with HTTP status code 401; discarding 1 replication tasks`...

Comment: your eureka service also need to set security serviceUrl

Comment: I am facing the same execption. Found any solution?

Answer (score 11):

SET eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone of eureka-server
http://username:password@localhost:8761/eureka/

Comment: I have tried with user name and password, still same issue

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [jacky-fan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6864388/jacky-fan) answer.

These are how my working configuration looks like without username and password.

server application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-service
server:
  port: 8302
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false 
    fetch-registry: false
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8302/eureka/
  server:
    wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty: 0
```

client application.yml

```
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8302/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
spring:
  application:
    name: my-service
server:
  port: 8301
```